# Questions about the Zappa–Szép product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Which groups with composite order are not a Zappa–Szép product of smaller groups ?

A solvable group with a composite order is always a Zappa–Szép product of smaller groups, but I am not sure about the non-solveable case. If the group has a normal-Hall-subgroup, it is a Zappa–Szép product of smaller groups.

> If not every group with composite order is a Zappa–Szép product of smaller groups, what is the smallest counter-example ?

Comment: Is there a simple reason why $A_5$ isn't a counter-example? For example, the canonical copy $K$ of $A_4$ is a $\{2, 3\}$-Hall subgroup of $A_5$ so we can pair it with some cyclic group $H$ of order $5$ with $H\cap K=1$, but it is not clear (at least to me) that $HK$ is a group. Or is it (well-)known that this is a group?

Comment: If $H=<(1,2,5),(1,4)(2,5)>$ and $K=<(1,2,3,5,4)>$ then $HK$ is isomorphic to $A_5$

Comment: It is not just isomorphic to $A_5$, it is equal to it. In this case $|HK| = |H|K|/|H \cap K|| = 60$ so we must have $HK=A_5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group ${\rm PSU}(3,3)$ cannot be expressed as a product of Z-S product of smaller groups. The group has order $6048$ and you can check in GAP that the orders of its subgroups are

```
{1, 2, 3, 4 ,6, 7, 8, 9,12, 16,18, 21, 24, 27, 32, 48, 54, 96, 108, 168, 216, 6048}
```

No two of these have product $6048$.

I conjecture that this is the smallest example, but I might be wrong! I am confident that it si the smallest simple example.

*Edit*: As Peter points out, $A_6$ is a smaller simple example!

Comment: According to my calculations , the simple group $A_6$ is already a counter-example.

Comment: Yes you are right! For some reason I thought it was a product of subgroups of orders 10 and 36, but it isn't!